# Why no URLEncoder.encode(String, Charset), URLDecoder.decode(String, Charset)

Tags: java, character-encoding, urlencode, urldecode

I'm not sure if SOF is the best place to ask this, but something about the java [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html).

For URLEncoder, it has the method `encode(String, String)` where the second parameter is the name of the encoding to use. If the encoding is not valid, then an `UnsupportedEncodingException` is thrown. It is a checked exception, so a try-catch statement must be used when calling `encode()`. This makes sense in terms of using a String encoding...

But Java has the [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class built in and you can easily access the `Charset` object of your favourite encoding using [Java's StandardCharsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) or [Guava's Charsets](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Charsets). This would prevent needing to catch an exception that you know will never be thrown if you fed `encode()` a correctly-spelt encoding name. Without the ability to use a method like `URLEncoder.encode(String, Charset)`, the code I write becomes really ugly because I need to store an extra String variable to store the encoding name and I have a pretty redundant try-catch statement, like so:

```
private static final String utf8 = "UTF-8";
...
String msg = ...;
try {
    String encodedMsg = URLEncoder.encode(msg, utf8);
    ...
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // This exception should never happen
    System.err.println("Uh oh...");
}
```

The same logic applied to `URLDecoder.decode(String, String)`.

So therefore, I'm just wondering, why does Java not have `URLEncoder.encode(String, Charset)` nor `URLDecoder.decode(String, Charset)`? Do the developers of the Java language have any plans on supporting this? It would turn the multi-line monstrosity I wrote above into a more pleasant one-liner that doesn't require me catching an exception I know will never occur unless the government made UTF-8 a crime. Are there any existing implementations or libraries that improve on this missing feature from URLEncoder and URLDecoder? I tried searching up for something in Guava, but found nothing.

Comment: My guess is just timing -- URLDecoder came out with JDK 1.0 and Charset came later with JDK 1.4.  [`YourCharset.name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#name%28%29) returns the canonical name, which you should be able to pass to `decode()` without fear of an exception.

Comment: @jedwards you should make that an answer.

Comment: You don't 'need to store an extra String variable'. That was your choice. The compiler would have pooled all the "UTF-8"s together anyway. Questions about future Java development should be addressed to the future Java developers, not SO.

Answer (score 5):

I can't say for sure, but my guess is just timing -- URLDecoder came out with JDK 1.0 and Charset came later with JDK 1.4.

[`YourCharset.name()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#name%28%29) returns a String containing the canonical name, which you should be able to pass to decode() without fear of an exception.